# Why is NetLogo's in-radius so slow, is there a faster way around it?

Tags: netlogo

I was finding my model was running very slow and I narrowed it down to an in-radius command that the turtles are running. The bottom line is that out of the two procedures below, test1 checks [var] of every patch but runs faster than test2 which should only check a small subset of 8 patches.

```
set patches-of-interest (patch-set patches with [var > 1])   

to test1
  ask min-one-of other patches-of-interest with-max [var][distance myself][set pcolor red]
end

to test2
  ask min-one-of other patches-of-interest in-radius 1.5 with-max [var][distance myself][set pcolor yellow]
end
```

You can check their speeds using the Profiler extension and the following code:

```
profiler:start         
repeat 100 [ 
ask one-of turtles [test1 test2]
 ]      
profiler:stop         
print profiler:report  
profiler:reset
```

Firstly, why is test2 running slower? And secondly, is there an alternative to test2 which does approximately the same thing but more efficiently?

I found a couple discussions on the Netlogo list about this but they're a bit old so may be out of date:
https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/issues/402

http://netlogo-users.18673.x6.nabble.com/Re-in-radius-efficiency-question-td5003840.html

EDIT: I left out that in my model I'm actually using a patch-set not the full "patches".  I've updated the code example above, but Bryan already partially explained the reason for the slowdown in the comments. Bryan is right that if using all patches, test2 is much faster, but I haven't been able to subset the patches in advance or within the two tests without slowing down test2.

Comment: Try putting parentheses around `patches in-radius 1.5`. `in-radius` checks on all patches can be optimized, but `in-radius` checks on other patch-sets cannot be.

Comment: I got a chance to test this out and I'm getting quite different results from. `test2` runs significantly faster than `test1` for me. I'm using identical code to what you posted. I initialized the model with a single turtle and initialized each patches' `var` several different ways: `0`, `random 10`, `random 2`, `random-float 1`, etc. In all cases `test2` runs significantly faster. How are you initializing the world? What version of NetLogo are you using?

Comment: I tested it with the updated information from your post. For me test2 is also running slower than test1. I tried to define the in-radius patchset before the ask statement and now it runs significantly faster, even faster than test1 `set patches-in-radius other patches in-radius 1.5`
  
  `ask min-one-of patches-in-radius with-max [var] [distance myself][set pcolor green]`

Comment: @tyr, your version is running faster because in your `set patches-in-radius` line you're using `patches` instead of a limited patch-set `patches-of-interest` as in my edited version. Fixing this, it runs the same as my test2 above.

Comment: @cwren, yes you´re right. If I use the previously defined `patches-of-interest` patchset my version is also much slower. I just tested the following: In my example I changed the `patches in-radius 1.5` statement to `patches-of-interest with [distance myself <= 1.5]` ... it is now as fast as test1. But I don`t know why the distance command is faster than in-radius.

Answer (score 2):

@bryan-head gave the reason for why the code is slow (in-radius checks on patch-sets cannot be optimized). I assume this is something internal to Netlogo's code.

However, I did finally find a work around that speeds things up and has the same effect so I thought I'd post it. First add the patch variable binaryvar then,

```
ask patches [ifelse var > 1 [ set binaryvar 1][set binaryvar 0]
to test3
  ask min-one-of other patches-of-interest in-radius 1.5 with-max [var * binaryvar][distance myself][set pcolor yellow]
end
```

Of course this still fails if all the cells in-radius also have var = 0...